# Error messages: result.rejectvalue 3rd argument

Tags: spring-mvc

in the following code what is the point of the third argument to rejectValue ?

```
errors.rejectValue("descriptions", "second_lang_desc_required", new String[] { secondLang.getCode() },  null );
```

I have this in the message value :  **Description in second language of application required {0}**  but this is exactly waht I see in the JSP, no replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spring [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String-) the purpose of the third argument is to provide a string array of arguments for replacing vars in messages.

In other words and telling from your code example its exactly what you expected it to be.

I guess you already checked if `secondLang.getCode()` is different from `null`. If so please have a look at whether or not you are using the latest release of `org.springframework`.

It is working in 4.2.4 but I remember having had to use a workaround before switching to 4.2.4 (Yes, of course - a clever guy would check change history and would 'know' instead of assuming, but I never claimed to be one, did I?)